# Why does "this" being an object in java have access to the private variables?

Tags: java, oop

I am very confused as to why `this` which is an object have access to the private variables of class. Whereas other normal object has obligation in it. For example:

```java
class Data{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    Data(int id){
        this.id = id;  // this is also an object refers to d
    }
    
    int getId(){
        return this.id;  // ok
    }
}

//driver class

class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Data d = new Data(1);  // in this context d is a "normal object"
       System.out.println(d.getId()); 
       System.out.println(d.id);  // not ok
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on the subject, e.g. [this one at `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). --- "*Whereas other normal object has obligation in it.*" - What do you mean by this? --- If `this` wouldn't have acces to `private` fields, who would have? The field would then basically be unusable.

Comment: what I have understood that first: `this` is an object and second: object outside of the class have no access to the class private variables. I am just joining this two concepts together... I hope you got my point.

Comment: `this` "is-a" `Data` and therefore has access to private fields.

Comment: `this` isn't special. It's just a reference to the current instance of the class. You could have `getId(){ return id;}` no this at all. Also you can reference fields of a different instance, eg. `public boolean test( Data other) { return id==other.id;}`

Comment: `this` _isn't_ an object outside of the class.  It's an object of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`private` means: Is accessible to everything in this source file that isn't in a sibling other top level class.

Given that you rarely put more than one class at the 'top level' of a source file, that boils down to: "everything in this source file".

So why does it work in `Data` and it does not work in `Driver`? Because `Data` is defined in `Data.java` and all code there can see it.

Why is that? Because the java spec says so, not sure there's much more to it than that.

Answer (score 0):

`priavte` means private to outsiders.

For example:
If your home is a class, then a TV within your home is private and accessible to people living in the home; but it is `private` to neighbors.

This is what is happening here.

When you add a `public` way to access TV, lets say a window from where neighbor can watch the TV (the `public` window is `getId()`).

Now whether neighbors can increase or decrease the volume of the TV, you provide other windows (like `setId()`) .
So, in a way it is a security mechanism where `encapsulation` of private things help you to control who can access it.

Answer (score -1):

yes you are right in this question asking.

let me explain why this happened

1. You know that `private_variables` can be accessed in the class itself otherwise no.

   - so `this` here means It's told you this variable for this class only otherwise no if it's `public, private, ..etc` think about it like that.
   - `this` not means object it's alias for an object (appropriate place for an object)

Comment: why not useful Can I know? to improve